# Callbacks in COM objects

Tags: c++, callback, com, atl, idl

I have an ATL project which exposes a COM object. I would like my COM object to call a function specified by the consumer from time to time, or via some other means of notifying the consumer from time to time.

I have tried adding a method in `CerberusNative.idl` in order to take void function pointers which I would like to call from the COM instance side of things so that the consumer would just need to tell the COM object upon initialization what its callbacks are:

```
interface ICerberusSession : IDispatch {
    [id(5)] HRESULT SetCallbacks([in] void(*userExit)(int, char *), [in] void(*userAttemptingReconnection)(), [in] void(*userReconnected)());
};
```

However, there are some problems with my void function pointers:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MIDL2269    procedures in an object interface must return an
>   HRESULT : [( Parameter 'userExit' ) ] Error   MIDL2131    parameter must
>   not be a function : [ Parameter 'userExit' of Procedure 'SetCallbacks'
>   ( Interface 'ICerberusSession' ) ]

In what ways can I get a client application to subscribe to callback functions in my COM object?

Comment: Follow-up question if anyone can help or is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006702/setting-up-my-atl-com-callback-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to define a separate interface with methods on it, and to pass that interface into my setter method:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(AECE8D0C-F902-4311-A374-ED3A0EBB6B49),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICallbacks : IUnknown
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT UserExit([in] int errorCode, [in] BSTR errorMessage);
    [id(2)] HRESULT UserAttemptingReconnection();
    [id(3)] HRESULT UserReconnected();
};

[
    object,
    uuid(B98A7D3F-651A-49BE-9744-2B1D8C896E9E),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICerberusSession : IDispatch {
    ...
    [id(5)] HRESULT SetCallbacks([in] ICallbacks* callbacks);
};
```